# Power Shell Script for Sure SMS Gatway to generate URL Request and send SMS via server

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, command-prompt

I am using an SMS gateway, which I often need to make an HTTP request to the server and get an SMS sent. I have a file with extension .sms with two parameters. The phone number and message body. I have to upload that file in the directory. I want to write a power shell script that should pick up each file and create an HTTP request to the server with a phone number and message in the URL.

The documentation on the URL here: https://developer.suresms.com/https/
The script should work like this way.

First scan the directory which contains the .sms files, then extract the data (Phone Numbers and Messages one by one in the file), then make the URL Request (for each record in the file) and post it on the server for sending the SMS message. When the work with one file is done, the program should make a directory(with name as "Finish") and move that finished file to the Finished directory. The Job has done. The program should display a message when all files worked in this way.

I tried it but I am unable to write such a script, as I am not much familiar with the scriptwriting. I need your guideline for this kind of work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start like that.

```
$ToDoDirectory = 'S:\Scripts\ToSend'
$FinishedDirectory = 'S:\Scripts\Done'
$urlTemplate = 'https://api.suresms.com/Script/SendSMS.aspx?login={0}&password={1}&to={2}&Text={3}'
$smsGateLogin = 'myLogin'
$smsGatePassword = 'myPassword'

$filesToDo = @([System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($ToDoDirectory,'*.sms', [System.IO.SearchOption]::TopDirectoryOnly))


for ($fileIndex = 0; $fileIndex -lt $filesToDo.Count; $fileIndex++)
{
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Processing SMS Files' -Status "$($fileIndex) of $($filesToDo.Count) done" -PercentComplete ($fileIndex / $filesToDo * 100)
    $smsFile = $filesToDo[$fileIndex]
    $smsText = $null
    $smsNumber = $null
    # Somehow you get contents of your $smsFile to $smsText and $smsNumber variables
    # ...
    $uri = [String]::Format($urlTemplate, $smsGateLogin, $smsGatePassword, $smsNumber, $smsText)
    $requestResult = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri $uri
    # Maybe test for $requestResult.StatusCode
    $destSmsFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($FinishedDirectory, [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($smsFile))
    [System.IO.File]::Move($smsFile, $destSmsFile)
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I will test it and will let you know its working. Thanks again.

Comment: I have tested the code, but it runs without any progress. Sorry to ask, but should I need to change some parameters within the script? Like 'myLogin', 'myPassword' etc. If possible please mention. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Yes, you need. This is skeleton, you should set smsGateLogin, smsGatePassword ,  and add piece of code into `# Somehow you get contents of your $smsFile to $smsText and $smsNumber variables`